# Characteristic polyomial and eigen number of compelx matrix.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-exponential

How to compute eigennumbers of matrix 2x2 A:
$$ A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
3i&1\\
-1&3i
\end{array}\right]$$

I got the polynomial I think which is $a^2-6ia-8$ but am not sure what the eigenvalues would be.

The full problem is finding exp of $\frac \pi 6 A$.
Please help.

Comment: What remains is to solve the polynomial = 0. How do you solve a polynomial equation of degree two? You may need to go back to precalc and learn it, because it will be needed in many different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

As you said $p_A(x)=x^2-6ix-8$ so eigenvalues are $x$ such that $p_A(x)=x^2-6ix-8=0$ and so you get $x_1=2i$  $x_2=4i$. To find $e^{\pi A/6}$ i suggest you to consider if this matrix is diagonalizable, and if yes find the matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ is diagonal.